# Different number of calls to onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using RecyclerView for a list of 100 items. 11 of them initially appear on the screen. Decided to log onCreateViewHolder. Here are the results:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(...): viewHolder {
    //...
    Log.d("TAG","log message")
    //...
}
```

Now when the App starts, a couple of logs appear, and when I start to scroll, 4-5 more messages.
But when I add a counter:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(...): viewHolder {
    //...
    counter++
    Log.d("TAG","log message $counter")
    //...
}
```

12 log messages appear at the start, and again 4-5 more by scrolling.
Tried both several times; same results every time. Why without a counter, I only get two logs?

Comment: Read about [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#structure) to understand why this is happening

Comment: @ronginat I've read that. 12 calls makes sense. What actually confuses me is why I get only two calls without a counter?

Comment: @Bucket are You sure IDE is not collapsing duplicate logs?

Comment: @Pawel Is there such a thing in Android Studio? I checked settings but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: @Bucket I googled around and it seems it's specifically Logcat behavior introduced around android O.